# How to submit without having a submit button on the form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I have a submit  in `<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangePassword", new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "ChangePasswordComplete" }))`  without having a submit button on the form?

I yes, how? Let's say I want to submit the above when a user click on an input of type button simply?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use Javascript to post back the form, jQuery has a submit method you can use.

```
$("#FormId").submit();
```

But really, an input of type button is the same as submit, only it submits automatically so you might as well use that.

#### Progressive Enhancement

Alternatively, you can use the [jQuery Form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) plug-in to post a standard form (using `Html.BeginForm` or manually outputting the `<form />`) and that will work for people who don't have Javascript enabled on their browser.

Comment: Where do I include the form Id in the above?

Comment: Either inspect it in the browser to see it's id/ name or provide one using the htmlAttributes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493048(v=VS.100).aspx). You can also give it a class and use the jQuery class selector `.FormClass`, again, use the htmlAttributes to provide the class name like this `new { @class = "form-class-name" }` (the @ is required in C# as class is a keyword)